# Sources of Pythagoras' quotes

Tags: greeks, quote, pythagoras, sources

I have learned that there are many quotes attributed to Pythagoras. I am concerned with what the sources are and how reliable they are. I'll appreciate help.

Comment: A good introduction to Pythagoras is https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pythagoras/ It makes clear that we do not have any writings from Pythagoras himself: "Pythagoras wrote nothing, nor were there any detailed accounts of his thought written by contemporaries. "

Comment: See [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/28392/what-are-the-books-of-pythagoras)

Comment: The earliest reputable source is Aristotle, and even he is not very reliable in this case, see [Zhmud, "All Is Number"? "Basic Doctrine" of Pythagoreanism Reconsidered](https://www.academia.edu/3477804/_All_Is_Number_Basic_Doctrine_of_Pythagoreanism_Reconsidered). Most of the rest is taken from neo-Pythagoreans who lived at least five centuries later, and the most popular "source", The Life of Pythagoras by Iamblichus, is from seven centuries later. If you see a "quote by Pythagoras" you can safely assume that it is made up.